# Перевести сумму часов из формата 255:00:00 в натуральное число

Tags: excel

В *Excel* сложил часы и получил формат 255:00:00.

Как из часов сделать число 255 для дальнейшего умножения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в ячейке **числовое значение**.

То, что мы видим - *255:00:00* - формат отображения времени, на самом деле в ячейке находится число *10,6326388888889* (10 суток и часть 11-х)

Дата в *Excel* - целое число (1 сутки = 1). Время - дробная часть числа:

```
1 час = 1/24

1 минута = 1/24/60 = 1/1440

1 секунда = 1/24/60/60 = 1/86400
```

Количество часов в числе, показанном в таком формате:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ(A1*24)
```

в *A1* числовая запись. Если время без минут и секунд, можно без функции  *ЦЕЛОЕ*:

```
=A1*24
```

Количество минут/секунд:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ((A1*24-ЦЕЛОЕ(A1*24))*60)

=(A1*1440-ЦЕЛОЕ(A1*1440))*60
```

'==================

Если в ячейке **не числовое значение, но текст**.

В этом случае нужно извлечь часть текста и преобразовать его в число. Формулы для извлечения из текстовой записи часов/минут/секунд:

```
=--ЛЕВБ(A1;ПОИСК(":";A1)-1)
=--ЛЕВБ(ПРАВБ(A2;5);2)
=--ПРАВБ(A2;2)
```

Answer (score 0):

В теории в новую ячейку нужно вписать `=LEFT(A1, 3)`, где `А1` - ваша ячейка, `3` - количество знаков, которые хотите оставить. 
Вам стоит почитать эту статью -> [Excel Substring Functions: How (and Why) to Use Them](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-substring/)

Comment: Если в ячейке число, то текстовая функция не поможет. Если текст, то Left использовать можно, но в связке с поиском разделителя, ведь количество часов может быть выражено не только двузначным числом.

Comment: Вы действительно во всём правы, я не учел, того что в ячейке может быть дано число такого формата или количество часов может состоять не из трёх знаков.